# Funnel chart with bars

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

Is it possible to make the rectangle cut at the end of the right (As below image):

[image: Shape Image]

Tried to use the css `skew` but its cutting both ends, I need only right like funnel.

Comment: please describe your problem more specifically and the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use clipping with polygon.  My polygons go from upper left, to upper right, to lower right, to lower left.  I used the css `calc` function in order to make the offset relative to the end.  I did a 40px slant, but if you want more a slant, simply change that number.

```css
body {
  background:black;
}

.slant {
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - 40px) 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - 40px) 100%, 0 100%);
}

.slant.outside {
  width:200px;
  background:#1384dd;
}

.slant.inside {
  width:100px;
  background:#addafd;
}

.slant.insideInside {
  width:60px;
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="slant outside">
  <div class="slant inside">
    <div class="slant insideInside"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```